# How to Run Jetty Example with Ring in Clojure

Tags: clojure, jetty, leiningen, ring

I am following along with [this example](http://mmcgrana.github.com/2010/08/clojure-rest-api.html) on creating a simple web service in Clojure using ring and jetty.

I have this in my project.clj:

```
(defproject ws-example "0.0.1"
  :description "REST datastore interface."
  :dependencies
    [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
     [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "0.2.5"]
     [ring-json-params "0.1.0"]
     [compojure "0.4.0"]
     [clj-json "0.5.3"]]
   :dev-dependencies
     [[lein-run "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]])
```

This in script/run.clj

```
(use 'ring.adapter.jetty)
(require '[ws-example.web :as web])

(run-jetty #'web/app {:port 8080})
```

And this in src/ws_example/web.clj

```
(ns ws-example.web
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use ring.middleware.json-params)
  (:require [clj-json.core :as json]))

(defn json-response [data & [status]]
  {:status (or status 200)
   :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
   :body (json/generate-string data)})

(defroutes handler
  (GET "/" []
    (json-response {"hello" "world"}))

  (PUT "/" [name]
    (json-response {"hello" name})))

(def app
  (-> handler
    wrap-json-params))
```

However, when I execute:

```
lein run script/run.clj
```

I get this error:

```
No :main namespace specified in project.clj.
```

Why am I getting this and how do I fix it?

Comment: The tutorial you linked to uses Leiningen 1.x - you should probably be using lein2.

Comment: It would be great if I could find a tutorial that just worked since I'm learning.  Any suggestions?  I want to create a web service in Clojure

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because the purpose of `lein run` (according to `lein help run`) is to "Run the project's -main function."  You don't have a `-main` function in your `ws-example.web` namespace, nor do you have a `:main` specified in your `project.clj` file, which is what `lein run` is complaining about.

To fix this, you have a few options.  You could move the `run-jetty` code to a new `-main` function of the `ws-example.web` function and then say `lein run -m ws-example.web`.  Or you could do that and also add a line `:main ws-example.web` to `project.clj` and then just say `lein run`.  Or you could try using the [`lein exec` plugin](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) to execute a file, rather than a namespace.

For more info, check out the [Leiningen Tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#running-code).

Answer (score 2):

You have to put that `(run-jetty)` stuff into a `-main` somewhere and then add it to the `project.clj` like

```
:main ws-example.core)
```

Comment: thanks, do you have a suggestion about the somehwhere?  the run-jetty stuff is located in a script called run.clj.

Answer (score 0):

From `lein help run`:

```
USAGE: lein run -m NAMESPACE[/MAIN_FUNCTION] [ARGS...]
Calls the main function in the specified namespace.
```

So, you would need to put your `script.clj` somewhere on the project source path and then call it as:

```
lein run -m script
```

Comment: This is using lein2. Commands to `lein run` are slightly different in 1.x.